# Allow files to be shared, with a label

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, external-sharing

Label within AIP/ARM can be used to restrict sharing with external users. But is there a way to do the opposite?

So I would like to allow users to share specific files when a certain label is added. For instance, when added 'Public' as a label the user most be allowed to share this file with a non-tenant-user?

Any heads up in a good direction?

Comment: Have you looked at DLP (Data Loss Prevention)? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/data-loss-prevention-policies?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fOverview-of-data-loss-prevention-policies-1966b2a7-d1e2-4d92-ab61-42efbb137f5e

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 platform workflow, there is action called "Replace item level permission " in Impersonation step, it will stop inheriting all parent permission to current item, and assign new permission to current list item.

You can create SharePoint 2010 platform workflow from SharePoint Designer, use if condition to judge if a certain label is added, then "Replace item level permission" for users on current item.

Choose start the workflow automatically when an item is created/modified.

For more detailed information, refer to the article about using a Workflow to remove or change document permissions:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/

https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-toset-sharepoint-item-level-permissions-based-on-column-or-field-values.html